# radius accept all, but refusing client?

Tags: mysql, radius

I have set up a radius I need for some authentication testing. However, it needs to just accept any and all requests so I have put a `"DEFAULT Auth-Type := Accept"` to fix that.

However, when I then test I get this from the log:

> Error: Ignoring request to authentication address * port 1812 from
>   unknown client  port 42159

So I googled it and found that even though its set to allow all it still needs the IP in the clients.conf? So treid that, but now im getting:

> Error: rlm_sql_getvpdata: database query error Error: [sql] SQL query
>   error; rejecting user

Is there not any way I can accept everything without adding them as clients first?

If not how do I fix the SQL issue? I followed a guide so everything should be right.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a client that covers the entire ipv4 range with:

```
client all {
    ipaddr = 0.0.0.0/0

    secret = <secret>
}
```

Please post the output of `radiusd -X` around the SQL error, as it's not possible to tell what's going on from that single log line.

Comment: I added the client all and started it in debug mode.

Then it failed with this:

Comment: I added the client all and started it in debug mode.

Then it failed with this:

client all {
Can't find IP address for host 0.0.0.0/0

/etc/freeradius/clients.conf[175]: Error parsing client section.
Failed to load clients

Comment: Upgrade to one of the v3.0.x series.

Comment: v3 fixes tons of stuff.  It's a shame the package maintainers haven't moved away from 2.